# How to get view image uploaded from paperclip in rails app in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip in my rails app.  In the development environment, when I go to the url where the image is stored I am able to view it.  However in production, I get an error saying that this page does not exist.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you hosting the application on? If it's Heroku, then it will not allow uploads, because Heroku has a read-only file system. Therefore, you will have to look for a third party solution such as S3 to host your uploaded images.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using for production. Some places like Heroku won't allow you to host images, so you need to use something external such as Amazon S3. Also, to get the url you can go to rails console and try to get the url of the image by typing in an instance of the model that has an image attached to it and then calling .image.url (assuming image is the name of the column)